# how to use hibernate and spring with javafx

Tags: spring, hibernate, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX application,but i have problems with combining JavaFX and Spring. What am I doing wrong in the Spring configuration is what I dont understand. Here is my code for JavaFX :
Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {
private static final SpringFxmlLoader loader =new SpringFxmlLoader();
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {

        Parent root=(Parent)loader.load("/com/isims/view/PatientAjt.fxml");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Controller:

```
@Repository
public class PatientAjtController {
    @FXML
    private TextField id;
    @FXML
    private TextField name;
    @FXML
    private TextField surname;
    @FXML
    private TextField adresse;
    @FXML
    private TextField numtel;

    @Autowired
    IPatientService ipatientservice;
     public IPatientService getIpatientservice() {
            return ipatientservice;
        }

        public void setIpatientservice(IPatientService ipatientservice) {
            this.ipatientservice = ipatientservice;
        }


    // Event Listener on Button.onAction
        @FXML

    public void handleBtnAjt(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {


        Patient p= new Patient();
        p.setId(Integer.parseInt(id.getText()));
        p.setName(name.getText());
        p.setSurname(surname.getText());
        p.setAdresse(adresse.getText());
        p.setNumtel(Integer.parseInt(numtel.getText()));
        getIpatientservice().addPatient(p);
        }
    }
```

SpringFxmlLoader:

```
public class SpringFxmlLoader {

 private static final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("SpringXMLConfig.xml");

 public Object load(String url) {
  try (InputStream fxmlStream = SpringFxmlLoader.class
    .getResourceAsStream(url)) {
   System.err.println(SpringFxmlLoader.class
    .getResourceAsStream(url));
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call(Class<?> clazz) {
     return applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
    }
   });
   return loader.load(fxmlStream);
  } catch (IOException ioException) {
   throw new RuntimeException(ioException);
  }
 }
}
```

SpringXMLConfig.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
">
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.isims.service"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

ERROR:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.isims.controller.PatientAjtController] is defined
```

**ADD:**
i tried to use Java config :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
//@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-client-security.xml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.isims.controller", "com.isims.service" })
public class SpringApplicationConfig {

}
```

Error in this line :

```
getIpatientservice().addPatient(p);
```

Thanks.

Comment: @WeareBorg Why would you want to exclude the controller from the base-package scan?

Comment: @James_D : I think I meant that for annotation with Controller, but it requires correction.

Comment: Annotate the controller class with `@Controller` or `@Component`. Also, is it a good idea to connect to Database directly from the JavaFX app? You can always have some server-side webapp running which will provide you with all the information required rather than connecting to it, which creates its own risks.

Comment: @WeareBorg I guess we are interpreting the question differently. I assumed this was a standalone client application, not a client-server app (or a client side app that communicates with a web service, etc). So there may not be a server to host the data layer at all; I kind of assumed Hibernate was connecting to an embedded DB (Derby or SQLite for example). But hopefully the OP will elaborate.

Comment: @James_D : Even in that situation if there is an embedded DB, data is scattered around with all the clients who install the app. But we will wait for OP to elaborate(reveal) why a DB with FX app?

Comment: Yes, it is a standalone application .I followed this tutorial:
http://fx-007.blogspot.com/2014/11/spring-4-hibernate-4-on-javafx.html

Comment: If it is finding the controller with your Java config file, but not with the equivalent xml configuration, either you have a typo in the xml config (check the package name again...), or your xml is not getting deployed when you save it. Check the build folder (depends on your IDE, etc) and check the xml config file there (i.e. not the one in the source folder). The error you are getting with the Java config seems like a completely different issue that is only appearing once you have solved the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

The package containing your controller is not scanned. Try

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.isims.service, com.isims.controller"/>
```

instead of your current `context:component-scan` element.

It also doesn't really make sense to annotate the controller as a `@Repository`. Annotate it as a `@Component` instead. Additionally, if you were to load the same FXML file more than once, it would be very important that each time you loaded it you got a new controller instance (else all controllers would be referring to the same set of `TextField`s, etc). So you should scope the controller as a prototype:

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PatientAjtController {
    @FXML
    private TextField id;
    @FXML
    private TextField name;
    @FXML
    private TextField surname;
    @FXML
    private TextField adresse;
    @FXML
    private TextField numtel;

    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, instead of autoscanning the controller package, just declare the controller bean explicitly:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.1.RELEASE.xsd
">
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.isims.service"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean class="com.isims.controller.PatientAjtController" scope="prototype" />

</beans>
```

and remove the annotation from the controller class:

```
public class PatientAjtController {
    @FXML
    private TextField id;
    @FXML
    private TextField name;
    @FXML
    private TextField surname;
    @FXML
    private TextField adresse;
    @FXML
    private TextField numtel;

    @Autowired
    IPatientService ipatientservice;
    public IPatientService getIpatientservice() {
        return ipatientservice;
    }

    public void setIpatientservice(IPatientService ipatientservice) {
        this.ipatientservice = ipatientservice;
    }

    // etc etc ...
}
```

Autoscanning is probably preferable, but this might method might at least get things working.

Comment: i tried this solution but i still have the same problem : No qualifying bean of type [com.isims.controller.PatientAjtController] is defined

Comment: Yes....
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.isims.service, com.isims.controller"/>

Comment: OK, let me test and get back. (It's a long while since I used XML config.. no-one much uses that any more :). )

Comment: Ok, can you tell me if I can't use XML config , what can I use??

Comment: Well, I tested this and it seems to work. Omitting the package containing the controller class gives me the error you describe, including it allows it to work. Obviously I removed all the data access stuff. I usually use Java config these days, but you should be able to get this working. I guess make sure the updated xml config file is getting deployed to your build folder...? Can you force it to work if you explicitly define the controller bean  in the xml file?

Comment: See edit for explicitly defining the bean in the xml config file.

Comment: it doesn't work..i tried to use Java config ..see my answer

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? You get an error? What error?